# SQL First and Last Transaction Report

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL, that looks a little similar to the table below:

[enter image description here][image: 1]

My goal is to generate a first and Last Transaction report.
I want to know when did customer X make their first purchase and what is the date of their most recent purchase.
I would like to group my results by Store and add all the transaction if they happen on the same day.

For instance, if John do made 2 expenses at walmart on Jan 15th and that's their most recent transaction, I would like those two expenses to be Summed in my report.

Here is the final result I'd expect from a table like on the example above:

[enter image description here][image: 2]

With what I have tried so far,
I am only getting 1 value back

The SQL looks a little similar to

```
Select 
SN
, SID
, CustomerName
, BankAccount
, Min(TransDate)
, Max(TransDate)
, price
, store
From transaction
GROUp by 
SN
, SID
, CustomerName
, BankAccount
, Min(TransDate)
, Max(TransDate)
, price
, store
```

I know I have to use some types of nested query to get the result(maybe) but I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to show in price, I see 10 for Peter but that user has two 10 and 12, how did you decide that it should show 10 and 20 for other?

Comment: Break your goal into pieces you can accomplish. First step - for each <customer, store> tuple, find the two (or potentially one) dates that you need. Note that you should not assume the earliest (minimum) date is different from the most recent (maximum) date. Once you have that set of rows, you can then join to your table to retrieve the transactions you need. Apparently you intend to sum transactions - so THINK about what it means to include a column that is specific to a row and not aggregated. Hint - don't make your sample data too simplistic.

Comment: the ultimate goal is to pull the first Date of the first transaction of a given customer but also pull the last transaction of that customer... if the given customer has more than one transaction on the LastDate, the I want to sum up the amounts, if he only has a single transaction, I will return that single transaction in the report,.. @rs. does it make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try and pull out the customer info you need to filter out the rest of the data.  I would start with a CTE to get the MIN and MAX dates for each customer.  I would then JOIN that back up to the original table and just get the records for the Customer that are on that MAX date.

I would assume you have something that is more Unique then the customer name, and if so I would use that instead.  But here is what I came up with given the data you provided:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(SerialNumber int, SearialID int,CustomerName varchar(100), BankAccount int, 
                    TranDate date, Price decimal(10,2),TracerID int,Store varchar(20))

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
(2,2,'Peter Smith',14564,'1/1/2021',10,756,'Kroger'),
(1,1,'John Do',12345,'1/1/2021',10,156,'Walmart'),
(1,1,'John Do',12345,'1/15/2021',5,148,'Walmart'),
(1,1,'John Do',12345,'1/15/2021',15,148,'Walmart'),
(2,2,'Peter Smith',14564,'1/12/2021',12,756,'Kroger')

;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT Min(TranDate) FirstDate, Max(TranDate) LastDate, CustomerName
    FROM #tmp
    GROUP BY CustomerName
    )
SELECT T.SerialNumber,T.SearialID,T.CustomerName,t.BankAccount,C.FirstDate FirstTrans, C.LastDate,SUM(t.Price) Price,T.Store 
    FROM #tmp T
    INNER JOIN CTE C on t.CustomerName = c.CustomerName and t.TranDate = c.LastDate
GROUP BY T.SerialNumber,T.SearialID,T.CustomerName,t.BankAccount,C.FirstDate,C.LastDate,T.Store
```

Comment: So my solution looked a little similar to this.
I used an inner query without a temp table... But this can be done with a temp table as well

Select 
 T1.SerialNumber,
 T1.SerialID,
 T1.CustomerName,
 T2.FirstTrans,
 T2.LastTrans
FROM TransTable T1 
Inner JOIN -- original Table)
  (select 
   SerialNumber,
   SerialID,
   Min(FirstTrans) 'FirstTrans',
   Max(LastTrans) 'LastTrans'
  From TransTable
  GROUP BY SerialNumber, SeriealID
  ) T2
ON T2.LastTrans = T1.TransDate
AND T2.SerialNumber = T1.SerialNumber
AND T2.SerialID = T1.SerialID